# Rewriting "pretty" blog category URL with htaccess / add_rewrite_rule() causes 404 page

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I'm migrating a site between hosts and am having issues with what should be(!) a fairly simple rewrite of a "pretty" URL to display posts filtered by category.

`domain.xyz/category/cat_name/   =>   domain.xyz/blog/?wpc_term=cat_name`

Using .htaccess, the following rule works:

```
# Works, but redirects the browser
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ blog/?wpc_term=$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, the client wants the URL to remain the same in the browser - the URL should be *rewritten*, not *redirected* - but removing the redirect flag `[R=301]` results in a 404 page

```
# Doesn't work -> 404 page
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ blog/?wpc_term=$1 [L]
```

I've also tried the following in the theme's `functions.php` - this also 404s.

```
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^category/([^/]+)/?', 'blog/?wpc_term=$matches[1]', 'top' );
  flush_rewrite_rules();
});
```

The old server was a shared hosting provider with its own admin panel for adding redirects, so I've no idea how they implemented on that server - however, it all works fine there so it must be possible!

**EDIT** to add full .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Works, but redirects browser :(
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ blog/?wpc_term=$1 [L,R=301]

# Standard WP .htaccess follows...
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

WP is installed in webroot directory, not a subdirectory.

No other .htaccess files in subdirectories.

Comment: Can you add your entire `.htaccess` file to your question, thanks. Is WordPress installed in the `/blog` subdirectory? Which `.htaccess` file are you editing? Do you have additional `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?

Comment: @MrWhite I've edited the question to include the information you asked for - thanks

Comment: I'm assuming `blog` isn't a physical directory, so it makes sense why that would 404 with a Last rule flag. The default WordPress rule forwards everything to `index.php`, which is ultimately where those requests need to be routed.

Comment: @Milo that does happen if I use the [END] flag instead, resulting in a "hard" 404 - whereas with [L] the rewritten URL *does* get parsed by WP and results in a "soft" 404 page (perhaps because there are no posts with /category/cat_name/ as the slug?)

Comment: "because there are no posts with /category/cat_name/ as the slug?" - Yes, that is most probably the issue. WordPress routes the request based on the requested URL (the URL you see in the browsers address bar), not the URL you are rewriting to.